# How can I force margin-right 0?

Tags: html, css

My html and css is like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Data</title>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            body {  
                font-family: 'Arial';
                font-size: 9px;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }
            div.global{
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            div.left {
                float: left;
                width: 50%; 
                text-align: center;
            }
            div.right {
                margin-left: 80%;
            }
            div.center {
                margin-left: 35%;
                width: 485px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="global">
            <div class="left">
                <div style="width: 80mm; margin-left: -15px !important;"> 
                    data.... <br>
                    test....
                </div>
                <hr style="max-width: 80mm; margin-left:0; height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div style="width: 80mm; margin-right: 0 !important"> 
                    <table>
                        <tr style="padding-right:35px">
                            <td>Lamp</td>
                            <td align="right">test 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>No</td>
                            <td align="right">test 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td align="right">test 3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <hr style="max-width: 80mm; margin-left:0 height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">

            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="center">
            data 1 2 3<br>
            data 4 5 6
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

..........................................................

I want display table(table in class=right) on the far right

I try

...............

```
<div style="width: 80mm; margin-right: 0 !important">
```

..............

But id does not work

Is there anyone who can help me?

Update

Demos is like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/skfd7215/1/

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate this is an older post and I haven't tested this against the code that you have provided (so I can't guarantee it will work for your given scenario at this stage) but I was researching a solution for forcing relative elements to the right hand side via `margin-right` as well and found this little beauty:

```
.element {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Example codepen here https://codepen.io/jamie-endeavour/pen/GdrZao

Either way I hope you got sorted. It would be cool if you could share your solution since none of the above answers have been accepted!

Comment: it worked!! So far, your answer is the only one I found mentioning `margin-left:auto`. Since without it, `margin-right` never worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what `margin-right` does. `margin-right` just gives margin to the right hand side of the element. Try inspecting the element in chrome/firefox dev tools to see where the margin is being added.

Assuming your `global` class spans the width of the page, you can give `global`:

```
position: relative;
```

and `right`:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for more about positioning.

Comment: See my jsfiddle

Comment: Still not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve. You really shouldn't be positioning using margin, read up on position above. I tweaked your fiddle a bit, should give you somewhere to start: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbtww0eh/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can you flex to send the content right

```
<div style="width: 80mm; display:flex; justify-content: flex-end">
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx5jsdvv/)**

Comment: It does not display anything. You can try in jsfiddle